# How to create button to check uncheckable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 checkboxes and as an example i checked only two of them and i need to create a button to check the another 8 box and uncheck the other two (that already checked before) How i can do this?

```
<input id="test1" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test3" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test4" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test5" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test6" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test7" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test8" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test9" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test10" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

here simple example for your code

```js
$('input.check11').click(function(){
  $('input.check21').prop('checked',this.checked)
  $('input.check22').prop('checked', false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">

                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" class="check11" value="">all</span><br>
                    </label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">

                    <label> 
                        <span><input type="checkbox"  checked name="discounting" class="check22" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" checked   name="discounting" class="check22" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" class="check21" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" class="check21" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" class="check21" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" class="check21" value="">test1</span><br>
                    </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing the best approach is to add class to every checkbox that you want to invert, and for each checkbox with that class invert 'checked' property

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.invert').each(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    $this.prop('checked', !$this.prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('#button').click(function(){
      
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
           }
           else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
           }
        });
      
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test3" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test4" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test5" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test6" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test7" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test8" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test9" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test10" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />

<input type="button" id="button" value="click">
```

Please check the Code will help you out

thanks

Comment: u are just reversing the checks

Comment: As per the question " uncheck the other two (that already checked before) How i can do this?"  yes am reversing the check

Comment: u can check for two checks, then only reverse

Comment: Yes we can do that but the question was like "check the another 8 box and uncheck the other two (that already checked before) How i can do this?"
So i have to check of of them which is check and which are not

Comment: and he added only two

Comment: Yes the he has 10 check box out of which two are pre checked and den on click of a button he want to uncheck the pre checked and check the other check box .
Sorry but am not able to understand your concern @Durga

Comment: Well, you can shorten your command, as it only inverts the tickmarks, to somehing like: `$(function(){ 
  $('#button').click(function(){     
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      with ($(this)) prop('checked',!prop('checked'))
    });      
  });
});` --- sorry, just noticed, that is more or less, what @Mateusz Staniuk wrote already.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
 $('#btnClick').click(function () {
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        var $this =  $(this);
        $this.prop('checked', !$this.prop('checked'));
     });                            
});
            
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test3" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test4" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test5" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test6" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test7" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test8" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test9" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test10" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This answer , you need to loop in all check box and vice versa check

```js
$('#copyButton2').on('click',function(){
$('#AllCheckbox input').each(function(){
$(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop("checked")); 
})
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='AllCheckbox'>
<input id="test1" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test3" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test4" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test5" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test6" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test7" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test8" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test9" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
<input id="test10" type="checkbox" />test1 <br />
</div>
<button id="copyButton2">CheckOther</button>
```